# Can I enable Spring Integration message history inside a chain?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

If I add this to my context:

```
<integration:message-history/>
```

I get a message header populated with the names (ids) of all the named components through which the message has passed.

But if I have a chain:

```
<integration:chain id="inboundChain" input-channel="inboundChannel">
    <integration:transformer ref="myTransformer"/>
    <integration:filter ref="myFilter"/>
    <integration:router ref="myRouter"/>
</integration:chain>
```

I only get "inboundChain" in the list of components, as I can not add an id to the components nested in the chain.

Any way to get myTransformer etc into the message history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is no.

See spring forum post [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111191-Can-I-enable-Spring-Integration-message-history-inside-a-chain)